# PowerMock: WhiteBox.getMethod() : Getting a private method with no parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I need to access a private method in my unit tests which has no parameters. It seems that the two implementations of getMethod() require argument types as the last parameter.

Is there away to get around this?

I have tried :

```
WhiteBox.getMethod(myClass,"method",null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test pass with [powermock-reflect-1.5.5](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.5.5).

class:

```
public class Util {
    private void method() {}
    private static void staticMethod() {}
}
```

test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

public class UtilTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Method method = Whitebox.getMethod(Util.class, "method");
        assertNotNull(method);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticMethod() {
        Method method = Whitebox.getMethod(Util.class, "staticMethod");
        assertNotNull(method);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java.lang.Class the method getMethod is

```
Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

and this means that you can call

```
clazz.getMethod( "method" );
```

for a method wthout arguments. So  your Whitebox method can be called

```
Whitebox.getMethod(myClass,"method");
```

Comment: I've checked at http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.7/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html. - What "does not work" and how, exactly?

Answer (score -1):

```
WhiteBox.getMethod(MyClass.class,"method",null);
```